# How can calculate FFT of 3D array in C++ with FFTW library?

Tags: c++, matlab, fft, fftw

I have 3D array in MATLAB like below:

```
val(:,:,1) =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i   2.0000 + 2.0000i
   3.0000 + 3.0000i   4.0000 + 4.0000i


val(:,:,2) =

   5.0000 + 5.0000i   6.0000 + 6.0000i
   7.0000 + 7.0000i   8.0000 + 8.0000i
```

I take one dimensional FFT in MATLAB like below:

```
clear
close all
%3D ARRAY Init
A3D(:,:,1)=[1+1i,2+2i;3+3i,4+4i];
A3D(:,:,2)=[5+5i,6+6i;7+7i,8+8i];
n=size(A3D,1);
res=fft(A3D,n,1)
```

The Result of FFT is:

```
val(:,:,1) =

   4.0000 + 4.0000i   6.0000 + 6.0000i
  -2.0000 - 2.0000i  -2.0000 - 2.0000i


val(:,:,2) =

  12.0000 +12.0000i  14.0000 +14.0000i
  -2.0000 - 2.0000i  -2.0000 - 2.0000i
```

In C++ I wrote program like below, I convert input to row-major format and send to fftw_plan_dft_1d to make FFT but my result is not as same as MATLAB result?Anybody can help me to solve this problem?

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <fftw3.h>

int main()
{
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;

    int N = 8;

    in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        in[i][0]=i+1;
        in[i][1]=i+1;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("%f\t%f\n", in[i][0],in[i][1]);
}

    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(8, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p); /* repeat as needed */

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("%f\t%f\n", out[i][0],out[i][1]);
}


    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Users should note that FFTW computes an unnormalized DFT, the sign of whose exponent is given by the dir parameter of fftw_create_plan. Thus, computing a forward followed by a backward transform (or vice versa) results in the original array scaled by n.

So, you should normalize. Here's an example with normalizing and performing a backwards transformation to get the original values back which you'll notice will work (but won't work without normalizing). The values you expect are not those produced though. I don't know matlab so I can't explain that part.

```
#include <fftw3.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const fftw_complex& c) {
    return os << std::setw(10) << c[0] << " + " << std::setw(10) << c[1] << 'i';
}

void display(const char* title, const fftw_complex* arr, size_t N) {
    std::cout << title << ":\n";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
    }
}

void normalize(fftw_complex* arr, size_t N) {
    for(size_t bin = 0; bin < N; ++bin) {
        arr[bin][0] /= static_cast<double>(N);
        arr[bin][1] /= static_cast<double>(N);
    }
}

int main() {
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p, p2;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed;

    size_t N = 8;

    in = fftw_alloc_complex(N);
    out = fftw_alloc_complex(N);

    for(size_t i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        in[i - 1][0] = static_cast<double>(i);
        in[i - 1][1] = static_cast<double>(i);
    }

    display("in", in, N);

    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(static_cast<int>(N), in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    p2 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(static_cast<int>(N), out, in, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(p);

    display("out", out, N);

    normalize(out, N);
    display("normalized", out, N);

    fftw_execute(p2);
    display("backward", in, N);

    fftw_destroy_plan(p2);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
}
```

Output:

```
in:
  1.000000 +   1.000000i
  2.000000 +   2.000000i
  3.000000 +   3.000000i
  4.000000 +   4.000000i
  5.000000 +   5.000000i
  6.000000 +   6.000000i
  7.000000 +   7.000000i
  8.000000 +   8.000000i
out:
 36.000000 +  36.000000i
-13.656854 +   5.656854i
 -8.000000 +   0.000000i
 -5.656854 +  -2.343146i
 -4.000000 +  -4.000000i
 -2.343146 +  -5.656854i
  0.000000 +  -8.000000i
  5.656854 + -13.656854i
normalized:
  4.500000 +   4.500000i
 -1.707107 +   0.707107i
 -1.000000 +   0.000000i
 -0.707107 +  -0.292893i
 -0.500000 +  -0.500000i
 -0.292893 +  -0.707107i
  0.000000 +  -1.000000i
  0.707107 +  -1.707107i
backward:
  1.000000 +   1.000000i
  2.000000 +   2.000000i
  3.000000 +   3.000000i
  4.000000 +   4.000000i
  5.000000 +   5.000000i
  6.000000 +   6.000000i
  7.000000 +   7.000000i
  8.000000 +   8.000000i
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is not normalize or unormalize in FFT and iFFT result , My problem is differences between Matlab FFT and FFTW in c++!

Comment: @Alexanov Ok, what if you create a 1D array (`A1D(somthing) = [1+1i,2+2i;3+3i,4+4i],5+5i,6+6i;7+7i,8+8i]; res=fft(A1D);`) in matlab just as you did it in C++? Does that produce the same output as I have above? If so, you probably need to look at the 2d/3d fftw plans.

Comment: it is vice versa, I want to convert matlab code in C++,and take FFT in C++ as same as Matlab result .

Comment: @Alexanov I understand that. I was just thinking that it'd be good to test it out to see if it's possible to get the same result in both environments. If you are indeed successful in creating a plain 1D array in matlab and get the same values as in C++, that finding could be useful.

Comment: In 1D array I get the same value in C++ and Matlab, but I do not know   what shall I do for 3D array

Comment: @Alexanov I did some experiments but it's hard when I don't know matlab - so I failed. Perhaps you would be more successful if you asked how to convert your matlab 3D fft to C using fftw at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/).